# delete from database using checkbox in javaswing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

hey guys i have i JTable loaded with information from database , the first colum is a checkbox , but when i check it to delete it dosn't do anything , any help please ?

```
  for(int i=0 ;i<jTable1.getRowCount();i++){
                    if((boolean)jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRows()[i] ,0).equals(true)){
                        state.addBatch("delete from employees where employeenumber = " + jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRows()[i], 1));
                    }
                    state.executeBatch();                    
                }
```

i used this and it said Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
                  for(int i=0 ;i<jTable1.getRowCount();i++){
           try {
               if((boolean)jTable1.getValueAt(i ,0).equals(true)){
                   state.addBatch("delete from employees where employeenumber = " + jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRows()[i], 1));
               }                    
               state.executeBatch();
           } catch (SQLException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(checkbox_in_jtable_Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
            }
```

Comment: jTable1.getSelectedRows()[i] isn't what you want use, just use i

Comment: like this  
jTable1.getSelectedRows(i) ?

Comment: No, getSelectedRow returns those rows that are highlighted, pass i directly to getValueAt as the row value

Comment: i did it , it give me null pointer exception

Comment: Then the value you're trying to get is `null`. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

Well, its just a suggestion but you could add a `button` that says "save" or "commit". In the `button` you can do a `foreach loop` in which you check the `status` of the `checkbox` in the row, with a simple `if-else` condition you can do your `query` or simply `push` ids into an `array` to do a bulk `query`.

Otherwise, you could add a `listenning` or `changed event` to your `checkbox` in which you retrive the `values` of the row and do the `query`, more dynamic.

Comment: yes i have it in a button 'Delete ' but always giveme a null pointer Exception i dont know why

Comment: make sure this line `jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRows()[i], 1)` returns something and in what data type, `string` or `int`, as far as i can see, your query uses `integers`. I prefere using `catch(Exception e) { ... write e ... }`